# How to insert into for each field

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the table "macchine" that contains all the cars owned by a person.

the table "dispSicurezza" contains all the security device that each cars must have.

```
DispSicurezza             Macchine
------------            -----------
IDs Detail                 IDm  
1   red                    A
2   yellow                 B
3   blue                   C
```

I need to make a third table that contains for each car, all the security device contained in the table "dispSicurezza"

i want to achieve a  third table like this

```
DispSicMacch
-------------------
IDs IDm
1   A
2   A
3   A
1   B
2   B
3   B
1   C
2   C
3   C
```

I'm not really good in mysql hope you can help me.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i have edited my answer

Comment: *"i want to achieve a third table like this"* Do you really want to have a fysical table or is a selected resultset also fine..

Comment: i want to achieve a physical table

Comment: *"i want to achieve a physical table "* see @forpas answer as that one is the solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `create table as select...` with the cross join of the tables:

```
create table if not exists DispSicMacch as
select d.IDs, m.IDm 
from DispSicurezza d cross join Macchine m;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Xfb23V5MAjCxcqtoyPeJa/1).
Results:

```
| IDs | IDm |
| --- | --- |
| 1   | A   |
| 2   | A   |
| 3   | A   |
| 1   | B   |
| 2   | B   |
| 3   | B   |
| 1   | C   |
| 2   | C   |
| 3   | C   |
```

Comment: `create if not exists table DispSicMacch as ..` might be better not sure how the topicstarter will run this or need it for this user case otherwise it's `drop table DispSicMacch ; create table DispSicMacch ..` if a total refresh is required..

Comment: Sure if needed the OP will decide.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a basic `JOIN` between `DispSicurezza` and `Macchine`

```
SELECT IDs, IDm FROM DispSicurezza JOIN Macchine
```

Here's the complete documentation on `JOIN` in MySQL
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a table that match macchine with dispSicurezza.

The table should be:

```
ID  |ID_macchine | ID_dispSicurezza
1   |  A         |    1
2   |  A         |    2
3   |  A         |    3
1   |  B         |    1
2   |  B         |    2
3   |  B         |    3
1   |  C         |    1
2   |  C         |    2
3   |  C         |    3


CREATE TABLE macchine_dispSicurezza(
    id int NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
    id_macchine int,
    id_dispSicurezza int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_macchine) REFERENCES macchine(idM),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_dispSicurezza) REFERENCES dispSicurezza(idS)
);
```